# Search a record using a key in Yii1

Tags: search, model-view-controller, criteria, yii1.x

I want to return matching records when user search with a key, I am building an online shopping site so if user search for xyz then it should return all records that contain xyz in a particular column in database. Right now it will return if and only if an exact match found in the column and the current code

```
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $search=$_GET['search'];
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('name',$search,true);
    $items=Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```

right now it will return the records(name) that match xyz=name but my requirement is if user search for xy then also it should return xyz(name)

Answer (score 0):

There is a method `\CDbCriteria::addSearchCondition()`, here is it's signature:

```
public static addSearchCondition(string $column, string $keyword, boolean $escape=true, string $operator='AND', string $like='LIKE')
```

In you example you have to use it like:

```php
if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $search=$_GET['search'];
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('name', $search);
    $items=Item::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```

You can find more information in the official Yii API:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addSearchCondition-detail